# Remote Desktop with "VMware Unity Mode"

Tags: remote-desktop, virtualization, virtual-desktop

I often Remote Desktop (to another Windows server as another user) to run one of a few applications (including Windows Explorer itself) to perform various administrative tasks.

I am looking for a way to display remotely running Windows applications locally.

Virtual machines often have this functionality between the host and virtual system.  For example, in VMware Workstation, you can enable Unity Mode (see below) after installing the VMware Tools in the guest operating system.

> [Use Unity Mode - VMware Workstation Documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-8C477788-7700-4030-8C4A-039C02AABB74.html)
>
> In Unity mode, virtual machine applications appear on the host system
>   desktop, you can use the virtual machine Start or Applications menu
>   from the host system, and the virtual machine console view is hidden.

It seems feasible this functionality could be possible between any two computers via some form of remote desktop.

Does any remote desktop software for Windows include the ability to display remote applications along side local applications?

Answer (score 2):

This article seems to be exactly what you would be looking for.

https://serverfault.com/questions/192595/vnc-a-specific-app-only

[Terminal Services RemoteApp](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753844(WS.10).aspx) (Which is a Windows only program) seems to be just what you're looking for. However, other possible software from the linked article: VNC, Citrix, XenServer (The free version of Citrix without commercial support)